# How to get "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" message

Tags: ssh

I have working authentication using keys. So I have client's `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` inside server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` I'm wondering which files should I change to get following message?

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
51:82:00:1c:7e:6f:ac:ac:de:f1:53:08:1c:7d:55:68.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/isaacalves/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/isaacalves/.ssh/known_hosts:12
RSA host key for 104.131.16.158 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I've find one possible method here [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/471327/how-to-change-a-ssh-host-key):

1. Delete old ssh host keys: `rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*`
2. Reconfigure OpenSSH Server: `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`
3. NOT update all ssh client(s) `~/.ssh/known_hosts` files

Are there any other methods?

PS: this is for my better SSH understanding

Comment: You can 1) change the host's (server's) key(s), 2) change the host (i.e. change what computer is at the server address), or 3) change the client's record of the key (in its ~/.ssh/known_hosts file).

Comment: 2') use a name in the `ssh` command and change the resolution for that name to a different machine's address, using in roughly increasing complexity: your local hosts file, mDNS/avahi, a local DNS server or proxy, or a remote (real) DNS server.